# How to force a single line input in an Alert Dialog?

Tags: java, android, input, android-alertdialog

I have this AlertDialog showing up when the user presses the floating button. I don't want the user to be able to insert a multiple line input (i.e. ignoring her if she tries to press the enter key). How do I do this? Here's my code:

```
  final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Package creation").setMessage("Insert package name:").setView(input).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        CharSequence toastText;
                        if (input.length() > 0) {
                        /* save the package name in the database */
                            toastText = getString(R.string.toast_package_saved);
                        } else toastText = getString(R.string.toast_empty_text);
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                        input.getText().clear();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }).show();
```

Comment: The input view is an EditText?

Comment: Yes. Sorry: I forgot to add that line in the code! I will fix it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Xml**

Put `android:maxLines="1"` in the EditText from the input xml layout.

Also choose an `InputType`, as Frédéric Letellier mentionated in his answer.

For example, `android:inputType="phone"`

More info in [Specifying the Input Method Type](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

**In Java**

```
input.setMaxLines(1);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

In these examples, it is showed a setting for phone number. You can view the other types in [InputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

---

ps: Also in xml, you can use `android:singleLine="true"`, but this parameter is deprecated. So the first option sounds better.

Comment: Thanks! Java worked exactly as I wanted. **Note** In my specific case I needed `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`.

Answer (score 1):

**Define the maximum of lines alone without changing inputType isn't enough**

In your xml, to make it look like single line EditText :

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

And to prevent entering a new line :

```
android:inputType="text"
```

---

Which translates programmatically :

```
input.setMaxLines(1);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: This works in case of an xml... but as I'm using an **alert dialog** I need something that will do it from the java file (I guess, unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0):

Use below attribute for EditText i.e input View

```
        android:ellipsize="end"
```